# How to show profile field Values to one simple page in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, user-profile

i want to get the custom profile fields which i have made in user profile part,

i want to get that values and show on one simple page i have tried this one....

```
<?php print $profile['Personal Information']['profile_fname']['#value']; ?>
```

but its not working....

i want to show all the fields on that page....

thanks in advance,

Nitz

**UPDATE:**

i got the answer....

Comment: If you 'got the answer', you should post it as an answer to your own question here - that way others might 'get it' as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
// load profile fields
profile_load_profile($account); 

//print values - 
//note the variable names after $account-> are the names given when you created the custom fields for the user profiles
<?php echo $account->profile_first_name;?> 
<?php echo $account->profile_last_name;?>
```